# How to analyze or block window.property events using chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, blockchain, ethereum, metamask

I am trying to build a chrome extension that will listen to `MetaMask` - another chrome extension.
Like an ad-blocker that blocks some tabs from opening, I am trying to block some calls to `MetaMask`.

Web apps communicate with `MetaMask` chrome extension via `window.ethereum`.

How can I catch all calls to `window.ethereum` before `MetaMask` chrome extension does, and decide if to allow these calls to continue to `MetaMask` or block them?